# mousewheel, on scroll simulate a click on menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to confer at rotation of mousewhell, all links present in my menu (anchor text), 
on scroll (up or down) I would like to navigate by section of 100% of the page (all sections/div are at 100% of height of window screen).
This is the basic theme:
http://onistaweb.com/demo/wp/master/

I modify this script, but don't work perfectly (scroll is not regular, 
sometimes it enchants and doing a loop), why???
thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(a){function d(b){var c=b||window.event,d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),e=0,f=!0,g=0,h=0;return b=a.event.fix(c),b.type="mousewheel",c.wheelDelta&&(e=c.wheelDelta/120),c.detail&&(e=-c.detail/3),h=e,c.axis!==undefined&&c.axis===c.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(h=0,g=-1*e),c.wheelDeltaY!==undefined&&(h=c.wheelDeltaY/120),c.wheelDeltaX!==undefined&&(g=-1*c.wheelDeltaX/120),d.unshift(b,e,g,h),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,d)}var b=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var c=b.length;c;)a.event.fixHooks[b[--c]]=a.event.mouseHooks;a.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.addEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=d},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.removeEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null}},a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery)
```

// Relevant code

var lastAnimation = 0; var animationTime = 1000; // in ms var quietPeriod = 500; // in ms, time after animation to ignore mousescroll

function scrollThis(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) { var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

deltaOfInterest = deltaY;

```
if (deltaOfInterest == 0) {
    return;
}

// Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + animationTime) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
}

if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
        jQuery("#navbar ul .active").next().find("a").trigger("click"); 

} 

else {
    //sali su
    //alert("scroll up");
    jQuery("#navbar ul .active").prev().find("a").trigger("click");     
}
```

}

jQuery(document).mousewheel(scrollThis);

});